# Is Append Only database modelling supported in nHibernate through mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We wanted to use Append-Only database model (no update/delete only insert). I saw [append-only-models-with-nhibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4196/append-only-models-with-nhibernate) by ayende, but wondering how to do that through mapping only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post [append-only-models-with-nhibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4196/append-only-models-with-nhibernate) is a old post 15 Sep 2009 and may be at that time the method was there in that version of nHibernate. However I could not find the same in nHibernate 3.3 onwards. The reason unexplored. One cannot have Append only database model just way mentioned in the post.

However one can have and interceptor/event and collect the dirty objects and do evict from the session so that it can be inserted in the database again. I shall explore further and update the answer as to how to do the same.